# django-filter didn´t filter

Tags: django, django-tables2, django-filters

I use django-filters and django-tables2.
The table worked great and display records on screen.
But when I clicked on Filter button nothing happens.
See code bellow and the image.

tables.py

```
class servicotable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = servico
        fields = (
                    'id',
                    'dat_servico',
                    'tiposervico',
                    'num_protocolo',
                  )

class filteredservicolistview(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
        table_class = servicotable
        model = servico
        filterset_class = servicofilter
```

filters.py

```
class servicofilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    dat_servico = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = servico
        fields = ['num_protocolo', 'dat_servico', 'statusservico', 'tiposervico', 'usuario']
```

views.py

```
def consulta_create(request, id=None):
    queryset = servico.objects.all()
    f = servicofilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    table = servicotable(f.queryset)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=25)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    context = {
            "filter": f,
            "lista": table,
    }
    return render(request, 'consulta/consultateste.html', context)
```

consultateste.html

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if filter %}
    <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
        {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
        {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
    </form>
{% endif %}

{% render_table lista 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: By doesn't filter, do you mean when you click the filter button nothing happens? If so, check to see if you have any Javascript errors on the page that are causing your JS to fail.

Comment: i don´t have any javascript in my consultateste.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking a bit more, I think you need to change `table = servicotable(f.queryset)`to `table = servicotable(f.qs)`.

`FilterSet.qs` is the property that has the filtered queryset. `queryset` stores the queryset you passed into the object, so in this case, `all()`!

(As a side note, I think it might help your code a bit to use camelcasing for object names to distinguish them from functions.)

Comment: Great!!!!! It worked!!!!! Thanks. Now, i have a field to select a row but i don´t know how to get de id number in my views.py.

Comment: What do you mean "select a row"? It looks like you have the field such that someone could enter the item's ID and it would filter to that row.

Comment: Any object in your queryset has an `id`. If you slice the first item (`queryset[0].id`), you'll get its database id number (which is just autoincremented unless you say otherwise).

Comment: In my views.py i´m going to do "if request.method=='POST': print(ID)"

Comment: So you're submitting this as a form when someone selects a row? In that case, you'll need to pass it as a POST parameter and get it from the POST dictionary. You should see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST